# Android Set text in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

> I'm trying to create an alert dialog with an image header across the top, 2 buttons at the bottom and I want to set the text in the middle from code. However, I can't get the set text underneath the banner. I want to create something similar to the one on [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout). However, the text always ends up above the image as I don't know how to reference the textview in the dialog builder. Thanks

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
           .setMessage("Message" + message)
           .setPositiveButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        if (...) {...} 
                        else {...}
                   } else {...} 
               }  
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Shake again!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           })
           .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {}
           });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {}
    });

    alert.show();
```

The layout xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/yo3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogtext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: Why don't you add the dialog text in the layout filE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set the message with the way you do it.

In your custom layout the textview you have to set is the "dialogtext" TextView.
Try this...see that i get the custom view that i inflate and from that view i get the custom dialog (which you didn't actualy set before) and set the message to show after the build has taken place.
Actually you can have whatever custom view you want and set each element of the view as you prefer or even handle events on it

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
TextView messageView = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.dialogtext);


builder.setView(customView)
        .setPositiveButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               if (isNetworkAvailable()){

                    if (......;

                    } else {
                        ......
                    }

               } else {
                   .......;
               }    
           }  
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Shake again!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User cancelled the dialog

           }

    }).setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });

messageView.SetText("Message" + message);



AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {


    }
});
alert.show();
```